# Spring Failed Build , error when creating bean configDataContextRefresher

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

I am trying to build a simple Eureka client application by following this tutorial from Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/.
But when I run the application after I set up the application.properties file it fails to run the application with the following message.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configDataContextRefresher' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class 
[org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
    at nl.tudelft.cse.sem.template.ServiceRegisrty.ServiceRegisrtyApplication.main(ServiceRegisrtyApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/logging/DeferredLogFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.logging.DeferredLogFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My application.properties looks like this:

```
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

And my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.0-RC1")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Any idea what issue may have caused this?